Failing to retrieve google drive labels using google service account
I'm using google service account to interact with google drive - reading files and folders etc. It works fine but i can't retrieve labels. Even if i specifically require labelInfo in fields, it's never returned back (key is not in the response). With fields="files(*)" there are canReadLabels and canModifyLabels so it has some sort of idea about labels.
After long frustration I tried calling labels api directly using this resource https://developers.google.com/drive/labels/quickstart/python
Few things to note:

Label does exist in google drive
File i'm working with has badged label attached to it
Service account has access to "Drive Labels API" and "Google Drive API"
Google service account has been granted domain wide delegation for following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.labels.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly



I can see "Drive Labels API" metrics and it shows API being called with 100% failure rate. Error i'm getting back is the following:
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://drivelabels.googleapis.com/v2/labels?alt=json returned "The user doesn't have permission to perform the requested operation.". Details: "The user doesn't have permission to perform the requested operation.">
What permission is missing?

I'm certain by now there's a bug on Google API which prevents service account from receiving labels.
This only works if service account delegates as a user. Don't forget to grant scope in https://admin.google.com/u/3/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation
creds, _ = google.auth.load_credentials_from_dict(
        google_credentials,
        scopes=[
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.labels.readonly',
        ],
    )
delegated_email = 'google-drive-user-which-has-access-to-labels@gmail.com'
creds = creds.with_subject(delegated_email)
service = build('drivelabels','v2', credentials=creds)

response = service.labels().list().execute()
labels = response['labels']

Another note is you must provide labels to get labels for .files().list() endpoint and you must ask labelInfo in request. This is dumb. Though it does not need delegating user - just regular service account.
creds, _ = google.auth.load_credentials_from_dict(
        google_credentials,
        scopes=[
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.labels.readonly',
        ],
    )
service = build('drive','v3', credentials=creds)

files = service.files().list(
    includeLabels='3xXscpJERzhjTm0flou, hjTm0flou0rSNNEbbF', <-- you'll only get these labels
    fields="files(id, name, labelInfo)",
    pageSize=30
).execute()


Were you able to get this working? I noticed the same error from my side using a service account to via their Python SDK with the most basic request of viewing labels with readonly scopes label_service.service.labels().list(view="LABEL_VIEW_BASIC").execute()

Keep note of different services build('drivelabels','v2', credentials=creds) and build('drive','v3', credentials=creds). drivelabels vs drive
